spark performance boost 50% with parquet intermediate step - why, and how to reproduce in memory
I have a pipeline that does much exploding at the beginning (pyspark):
3 tgz files -> 3 pcap (untar is udf, gzip is native) -> * ~100000 udp packages (udf using dpkt library) -> * ~100 signal ticks (udf decoding proprietary binary format)
From here i do only pyspark sql on currently only 4 signals.
If run at once with 3 files it takes 14min on my 8 core/ 64GB machine on local spark.
If i store the dataframe after explosion (aka intermediate result) into parquet (size around 500MB) and start processing from parquet the time is reduced to 7min.
Is there a way to reproduce this within memory? Without i/o it should be faster?
What i tried without any effect on time (so there seems to be one big problem?):

cache() / persist() the intermediate result
checkpoint()
repartition with different columns and sizes

So how to get the performance boost without i/o penalty?

spark will consider any compressed raw files like *.gz as 1 partition, so if you have 3 partition, you can only parallelize 3 tasks, but if you decompress it or split these files into smaller chunks you can parallelize and use all your cpus, but with parquets spark can read by chunks and deserialization is faster through parquet protocol than raw file compression
